# Student Class Options

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database for a college.

I have the students assigned to a course, but in there course they get a list of class options. The class options are the same for each course (don't ask why, because i really don't know).

There's 4 periods in the week and 3 blocks in the year.

So they will need the dropdown of classes for all 12 options
i.e

```
Block1period1   Block2period1    Block3period1
Block1period2   Block2period2    Block3period2
```

I need to keep a record of classes taken from each block.

What would I need to do this?

I have my Options(classes) table and my student table.
What fields would I need in my Student2Classes table?

**Edit**:

I'll try explain my layout as best I can.

Currently in my database, I can add student information and assign them to a course. My student information is broken up into several tables Such as Personal Info, School Info, Emergency contact, transport method, etc. 
of which is added on numerous forms. 
To assign a student to a course I have a status dropdown on my main form for adding the information with options such as [completed assessment, accepted, not accepted] 
If Completed Assessment or Accepted are chosen, a Place offer subform appears where the student can be given a place offer and enrolled on a course. 
Now for this part I don't want the classes linked to the courses as the same subjects applies for most courses and options are chosen before they are accepted. 
So I want to have the option choices as a standalone without linking through the course.

So my main student table

```
[Student ID, 
first name, 
last name, 
etc.]
```

an Options Table

```
[Option ID, 
Option Name, 
Room Number, 
Tutor]
```

and now my ClassAssignments or Student2Classes

```
[ID,
student ID,
Options ID, 
Block, 
Period]
```

I can change the options or Student2Classes as needed. 
I don't have much experience with Access but I'd say I'm very comfortable with it 
there's just some things I'm lost at (this being one of them)

Comment: Have you had a chance to read something like http://r937.com/relational.html ?

Comment: I know the basics of access, im just not sure how to go about this part

Comment: This is not an Access question at the root, it is a database design question.

Comment: fixed, I know how to assign a single block of classes to the student, i just don't know how to go about the three blocks and to keep a record of the previous classes

Comment: So post the schema for the single block of classes.

Comment: the way i'd have it is to have my student table and my courses table listed in a Student2Classes table with Student2ClassesID, StudentID, CourseID and period

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15062/discussion-between-remou-and-sawyer05)